# How to draw gauge chart in R?

Tags: r, charts, gauge

How can I draw the following plot in R?

```
Red = 30
Yellow = 40
Green = 30 

Needle at 52.
```

[image: gauge chart]

Answer (score 40):

So here's a fully `ggplot` solution.

Note: Edited from the original post to add numeric indicator and labels at the gauge breaks which seems to be what OP is asking for in their comment. If indicator is not needed, remove the `annotate(...)` line. If labels are not needed, remove `geom_text(...)` line.

```
gg.gauge <- function(pos,breaks=c(0,30,70,100)) {
  require(ggplot2)
  get.poly <- function(a,b,r1=0.5,r2=1.0) {
    th.start <- pi*(1-a/100)
    th.end   <- pi*(1-b/100)
    th       <- seq(th.start,th.end,length=100)
    x        <- c(r1*cos(th),rev(r2*cos(th)))
    y        <- c(r1*sin(th),rev(r2*sin(th)))
    return(data.frame(x,y))
  }
  ggplot()+ 
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[1],breaks[2]),aes(x,y),fill="red")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[2],breaks[3]),aes(x,y),fill="gold")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[3],breaks[4]),aes(x,y),fill="forestgreen")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(pos-1,pos+1,0.2),aes(x,y))+
    geom_text(data=as.data.frame(breaks), size=5, fontface="bold", vjust=0,
              aes(x=1.1*cos(pi*(1-breaks/100)),y=1.1*sin(pi*(1-breaks/100)),label=paste0(breaks,"%")))+
    annotate("text",x=0,y=0,label=pos,vjust=0,size=8,fontface="bold")+
    coord_fixed()+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text=element_blank(),
          axis.title=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          panel.grid=element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank()) 
}
gg.gauge(52,breaks=c(0,35,70,100))
```

[image]

```
## multiple guages
library(gridExtra)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(arrangeGrob(gg.gauge(10),gg.gauge(20),
                      gg.gauge(52),gg.gauge(90),ncol=2))
```

[image]

You will likely need to tweak the `size=...` parameter to `geom_text(...)` and `annotate(...)` depending on the actual size of your gauge.

IMO the segment labels are a really bad idea: they clutter the image and defeat the purpose of the graphic (to indicate at a glance if the metric is in "safe", "warning", or "danger" territory).

Comment: How to value at each segment like 0%, 30%, 70%, 100%?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have just updated the image in my question. I need to add value at each segment as shown in figure. How can i do that?

Comment: @jhoward: How do you change the width of the needle?

Comment: @jlhoward How do I resize the size of the gauge?

Comment: @jlhoward Awesome post with code that is easy to follow and reuse. Rock on, dude!

Answer (score 11):

Here's a very quick and dirty implementation using grid graphics

```
library(grid)

draw.gauge<-function(x, from=0, to=100, breaks=3, 
    label=NULL, axis=TRUE, cols=c("red","yellow","green")) {

    if (length(breaks)==1) {
        breaks <- seq(0, 1, length.out=breaks+1)
    } else {
        breaks <- (breaks-from)/(to-from)
    }
    stopifnot(length(breaks) == (length(cols)+1))

    arch<-function(theta.start, theta.end, r1=1, r2=.5, col="grey", n=100) {
        t<-seq(theta.start, theta.end, length.out=n)
        t<-(1-t)*pi
        x<-c(r1*cos(t), r2*cos(rev(t)))
        y<-c(r1*sin(t), r2*sin(rev(t)))
        grid.polygon(x,y, default.units="native", gp=gpar(fill=col))
    }
    tick<-function(theta, r, w=.01) {
        t<-(1-theta)*pi
        x<-c(r*cos(t-w), r*cos(t+w), 0) 
        y<-c(r*sin(t-w), r*sin(t+w), 0) 
        grid.polygon(x,y, default.units="native", gp=gpar(fill="grey"))
    }
    addlabel<-function(m, theta, r) {
        t<-(1-theta)*pi      
        x<-r*cos(t)
        y<-r*sin(t) 
        grid.text(m,x,y, default.units="native")
    }

    pushViewport(viewport(w=.8, h=.40, xscale=c(-1,1), yscale=c(0,1)))
    bp <- split(t(embed(breaks, 2)), 1:2)
    do.call(Map, list(arch, theta.start=bp[[1]],theta.end=bp[[2]], col=cols))
    p<-(x-from)/(to-from)
    if (!is.null(axis)) {
            if(is.logical(axis) && axis) {
            m <- round(breaks*(to-from)+from,0)
            } else if (is.function(axis)) {
            m <- axis(breaks, from, to)
            } else if(is.character(axis)) {
            m <- axis
            } else {
                   m <- character(0)
            }
        if(length(m)>0) addlabel(m, breaks, 1.10)
    }
    tick(p, 1.03)
    if(!is.null(label)) {
            if(is.logical(label) && label) {
            m <- x
            } else if (is.function(label)) {
            m <- label(x)
            } else {
            m <- label
            }
            addlabel(m, p, 1.15)
    }
    upViewport()
}
```

This function can be used to draw one gauge

```
grid.newpage()
draw.gauge(100*runif(1))
```

or many gauges

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout=grid.layout(2,2)))
for(i in 1:4) {
    pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col=(i-1) %/%2 +1, layout.pos.row=(i-1) %% 2 + 1))
    draw.gauge(100*runif(1))
    upViewport()
}
popViewport()
```

It's not too fancy so it should be easy to customize.

[image]

You can now also add a label

```
draw.gauge(75, label="75%")
```

[image]

I've added another update to allow for drawing an "axis". You can set it to TRUE to use default values, or you can pass in a character vector to give whatever labels you want, or you can pass in a function that will take the breaks (scaled 0-1) and the from/to values and should return a character value.

```
grid.newpage()
draw.gauge(100*runif(1), breaks=c(0,30,70,100), axis=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! But there is no indicator based on ratios like 30%, 40% and 30% .In your example all three segment seemes to be equally spaced. Thanks

Comment: There's a `breaks=` parameter. You can set `breaks=c(0,30,70,100)` to get 30/40/30 if you like.

Comment: @Manish oops. also had a typo in there. fixed.

Comment: Great! But still i do not have control on needle at particular value in this plot. In your example pushViewport function changes the position of needle but not at desired position. Can u pls help me how can i control it. Thanks

Comment: The range goes from 0 to 100. If you want to draw at 0, do `grid.newpage();draw.gauge(0)` if you want to draw at 50, do `grid.newpage();draw.gauge(50)`. Each of those together is a complete plotting command. The first part erases what was there, the second draws the new plot.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the image drawn is anticlockwise based on segment it should be clockise and same goes to needle. Can u pls help how can i make it clockwise.

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise for you. I don't have time right now. I may be able to come back to it tomorrow.

Comment: I have done it by changing start to end. One more thing i need to put label at segment. Pls reply when ever you are free. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: I am using grid.text() function but it is not working.    grid.text("value", x=2, y=3, gp=gpar(fontsize=20), check=TRUE)

Comment: grid.text should have worked. But values of 2 and 3 seem off. the xaxis goes from -1 to 1 and y goes from 0 to .5. I've updated to switch the orientation and add a label.

Comment: I have just updated the image in my question. I need to add value at each segment as shown in figure. How can i do that?

Comment: You really need to make sure your question is complete when you post it. Adding additional request or changing the desired result puts an unnecessary burden on potential answers. If you have new requests, it's better to start a new question. That being said, in this case I did update the code to add an axis. Bur from now on you should be responsible for making any additional changes. SO is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 4):

Flexdashboard has a simple function for guage chart. For details take a look at https://rdrr.io/cran/flexdashboard/man/gauge.html

You can plot the chart using a simple call like:

```
gauge(42, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', 
gaugeSectors(success = c(80, 100), warning = c(40, 79), danger = c(0, 39)))
```

Comment: It looks good, but has a few limitations. 1. You can only use three colors, 2. It cannot be resized.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution from Gaston Sanchez's blog:

```
library(googleVis)

plot(gvisGauge(data.frame(Label=”UserR!”, Value=80),
options=list(min=0, max=100,
yellowFrom=80, yellowTo=90,
redFrom=90, redTo=100)))

Here is the function created later:

# Original code by Gaston Sanchez   http://www.r-bloggers.com/gauge-chart-in-r/
#
dial.plot <- function(label = "UseR!", value = 78, dial.radius = 1
          , value.cex = 3, value.color = "black"
          , label.cex = 3, label.color = "black"
          , gage.bg.color = "white"
          , yellowFrom = 75, yellowTo = 90, yellow.slice.color = "#FF9900"
          , redFrom = 90, redTo = 100, red.slice.color = "#DC3912"
          , needle.color = "red", needle.center.color = "black", needle.center.cex = 1
          , dial.digets.color = "grey50"
          , heavy.border.color = "gray85", thin.border.color = "gray20", minor.ticks.color = "gray55", major.ticks.color = "gray45") {

  whiteFrom = min(yellowFrom, redFrom) - 2
  whiteTo = max(yellowTo, redTo) + 2

  # function to create a circle
  circle <- function(center=c(0,0), radius=1, npoints=100)
  {
    r = radius
    tt = seq(0, 2*pi, length=npoints)
    xx = center[1] + r * cos(tt)
    yy = center[1] + r * sin(tt)
    return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
  }

  # function to get slices
  slice2xy <- function(t, rad)
  {
    t2p = -1 * t * pi + 10*pi/8
    list(x = rad * cos(t2p), y = rad * sin(t2p))
  }

  # function to get major and minor tick marks
  ticks <- function(center=c(0,0), from=0, to=2*pi, radius=0.9, npoints=5)
  {
    r = radius
    tt = seq(from, to, length=npoints)
    xx = center[1] + r * cos(tt)
    yy = center[1] + r * sin(tt)
    return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
  }

  # external circle (this will be used for the black border)
  border_cir = circle(c(0,0), radius=dial.radius, npoints = 100)

  # open plot
  plot(border_cir$x, border_cir$y, type="n", asp=1, axes=FALSE,
       xlim=c(-1.05,1.05), ylim=c(-1.05,1.05),
       xlab="", ylab="")

  # gray border circle
  external_cir = circle(c(0,0), radius=( dial.radius * 0.97 ), npoints = 100)
    # initial gage background
  polygon(external_cir$x, external_cir$y,
          border = gage.bg.color, col = gage.bg.color, lty = NULL)

  # add gray border
  lines(external_cir$x, external_cir$y, col=heavy.border.color, lwd=18)
  # add external border
  lines(border_cir$x, border_cir$y, col=thin.border.color, lwd=2)

  # yellow slice (this will be used for the yellow band)
  yel_ini = (yellowFrom/100) * (12/8)
  yel_fin = (yellowTo/100) * (12/8)
  Syel = slice2xy(seq.int(yel_ini, yel_fin, length.out = 30), rad= (dial.radius * 0.9) )
  polygon(c(Syel$x, 0), c(Syel$y, 0),
          border = yellow.slice.color, col = yellow.slice.color, lty = NULL)

  # red slice (this will be used for the red band)
  red_ini = (redFrom/100) * (12/8)
  red_fin = (redTo/100) * (12/8)
  Sred = slice2xy(seq.int(red_ini, red_fin, length.out = 30), rad= (dial.radius * 0.9) )
  polygon(c(Sred$x, 0), c(Sred$y, 0),
          border = red.slice.color, col = red.slice.color, lty = NULL)

  # white slice (this will be used to get the yellow and red bands)
  white_ini = (whiteFrom/100) * (12/8)
  white_fin = (whiteTo/100) * (12/8)
  Swhi = slice2xy(seq.int(white_ini, white_fin, length.out = 30), rad= (dial.radius * 0.8) )
  polygon(c(Swhi$x, 0), c(Swhi$y, 0),
          border = gage.bg.color, col = gage.bg.color, lty = NULL)

  # calc and plot minor ticks
  minor.tix.out <- ticks(c(0,0), from=5*pi/4, to=-pi/4, radius=( dial.radius * 0.89 ), 21)
  minor.tix.in <- ticks(c(0,0), from=5*pi/4, to=-pi/4, radius=( dial.radius * 0.85 ), 21)
  arrows(x0=minor.tix.out$x, y0=minor.tix.out$y, x1=minor.tix.in$x, y1=minor.tix.in$y,
         length=0, lwd=2.5, col=minor.ticks.color)

  # coordinates of major ticks (will be plotted as arrows)
  major_ticks_out = ticks(c(0,0), from=5*pi/4, to=-pi/4, radius=( dial.radius * 0.9 ), 5)
  major_ticks_in = ticks(c(0,0), from=5*pi/4, to=-pi/4, radius=( dial.radius * 0.77 ), 5)
  arrows(x0=major_ticks_out$x, y0=major_ticks_out$y, col=major.ticks.color,
         x1=major_ticks_in$x, y1=major_ticks_in$y, length=0, lwd=3)

  # calc and plot numbers at major ticks
  dial.numbers <- ticks(c(0,0), from=5*pi/4, to=-pi/4, radius=( dial.radius * 0.70 ), 5)
  dial.lables <- c("0", "25", "50", "75", "100")
  text(dial.numbers$x, dial.numbers$y, labels=dial.lables, col=dial.digets.color, cex=.8)


  # Add dial lables
  text(0, (dial.radius * -0.65), value, cex=value.cex, col=value.color)
  # add label of variable
  text(0, (dial.radius * 0.43), label, cex=label.cex, col=label.color)

  # add needle
  # angle of needle pointing to the specified value
  val = (value/100) * (12/8)
  v = -1 * val * pi + 10*pi/8 # 10/8 becuase we are drawing on only %80 of the cir
  # x-y coordinates of needle
  needle.length <- dial.radius * .67
  needle.end.x = needle.length * cos(v)
  needle.end.y = needle.length * sin(v)

  needle.short.length <- dial.radius * .1
  needle.short.end.x = needle.short.length * -cos(v)
  needle.short.end.y = needle.short.length * -sin(v)

  needle.side.length <- dial.radius * .05
  needle.side1.end.x = needle.side.length * cos(v - pi/2) 
  needle.side1.end.y = needle.side.length * sin(v - pi/2)
  needle.side2.end.x = needle.side.length * cos(v + pi/2) 
  needle.side2.end.y = needle.side.length * sin(v + pi/2)

  needle.x.points <- c(needle.end.x, needle.side1.end.x, needle.short.end.x, needle.side2.end.x)
  needle.y.points <- c(needle.end.y, needle.side1.end.y, needle.short.end.y, needle.side2.end.y)
  polygon(needle.x.points, needle.y.points, col=needle.color)

  # add central blue point
  points(0, 0, col=needle.center.color, pch=20, cex=needle.center.cex)
  # add values 0 and 100
}


par(mar=c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2), bg="black", mfrow=c(2,2))

dial.plot ()
dial.plot (label = "Working", value = 25, dial.radius = 1
      , value.cex = 3.3, value.color = "white"
      , label.cex = 2.7, label.color = "white"
      , gage.bg.color = "black"
      , yellowFrom = 73, yellowTo = 95, yellow.slice.color = "gold"
      , redFrom = 95, redTo = 100, red.slice.color = "red"
      , needle.color = "red", needle.center.color = "white", needle.center.cex = 1
      , dial.digets.color = "white"
      , heavy.border.color = "white", thin.border.color = "black", minor.ticks.color = "white", major.ticks.color = "white")


dial.plot (label = "caffeine", value = 63, dial.radius = .7
           , value.cex = 2.3, value.color = "white"
           , label.cex = 1.7, label.color = "white"
           , gage.bg.color = "black"
           , yellowFrom = 80, yellowTo = 93, yellow.slice.color = "gold"
           , redFrom = 93, redTo = 100, red.slice.color = "red"
           , needle.color = "red", needle.center.color = "white", needle.center.cex = 1
           , dial.digets.color = "white"
           , heavy.border.color = "black", thin.border.color = "lightsteelblue4", minor.ticks.color = "orange", major.ticks.color = "tan")


dial.plot (label = "Fun", value = 83, dial.radius = .7
           , value.cex = 2.3, value.color = "white"
           , label.cex = 1.7, label.color = "white"
           , gage.bg.color = "black"
           , yellowFrom = 20, yellowTo = 75, yellow.slice.color = "olivedrab"
           , redFrom = 75, redTo = 100, red.slice.color = "green"
           , needle.color = "red", needle.center.color = "white", needle.center.cex = 1
           , dial.digets.color = "white"
           , heavy.border.color = "black", thin.border.color = "lightsteelblue4", minor.ticks.color = "orange", major.ticks.color = "tan")
```